# ArcPy UpdateCursor - Adding different text to more than one row of a shapefile entity

Tags: arcpy, loop, update

I have the following code, which adds a field, and then a value to a row:

```
import arcpy

V1 = r"path/shapefile.shp"

# Add CODE field
arcpy.AddField_management(V1, "VERTEX", "TEXT", 5, "", "", "refcode", "NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")

# Update CODE field with CODE_TEST value
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(V1, ["VERTEX"]) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        row[0] = "V1"
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

The problem is that the text that you add to the first row adds it to the other remaining ones, as seen below:

[image]

I need to place the second record "V2", the third "V3" and so on, as shown in the image above. This develop it in a code.

PS: My shapefile is a point file, with four vertices.

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't request differing values for different rows. Why would applying a constant be expected to produce different results by row? Please [Edit] the Question to contain the code that actually makes the attempt (note that it would not involve `row[n]`)

Comment: Because the shapefile is a rectangle with four vertices and I need to place them in the attribute table to later convert them into labels and be able to represent them on a map.

Comment: A rectangle contains **five** vertices (the ring must close). Your code doesn't attempt anything with vertices.

Comment: Looks like you have "Exploded" your rectangle vertices into points (punto)? Is this correct? Does your shapefile only ever have the points of a single rectangle? Or do you have many points in a single shapefile because you had many rectangles in the shapefile?

Comment: This now appears to be an XY Problem (a question about an unusual/unreliable/unworkable solution to a problem, not the problem itself).  What was your original intent in going down this path?

Comment: @Hornbydd Does your shapefile only ever have the points of a single rectangle? --> Yes

Comment: @Vince I just need to put the second record "V2", the third "V3" and so on, in one code.

Comment: You don't attempt to do this in your code (which should include a reference to the FID column).

Comment: @Vince That is my question... Can V2, V3, and V4 be placed in an ordered manner in the following registers?

Comment: I would look at using the enumerate() function in python to give you your row sequence then its a simple concatenation of "V" with index number. There are many examples on this site showing the use of enumerate().

Comment: You'd need `enumerate(row,start=1)`

Comment: I don't understand why my post has a "-1" vote. I think it is a very interesting question, perhaps I wrote it incorrectly, since English is not my native language (it is Spanish).

Comment: Why don’t you just concatenate “V” with the value of FID plus one?  You could use the Field Calculator to do that.

Comment: @PolyGeo It's a good idea, although my idea is not to go into the software to do the work. I just want the script to do it, to have the file as fast as possible and get to work.

Comment: If you are expecting a certain order to the records, you must include an ORDER BY statement or there is no guarantee to the order of records when updating the text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a counter such as [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) into your script and then use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) to insert it into a string. For example:

```
import arcpy

V1 = r"path/shapefile.shp"

# Add CODE field
arcpy.AddField_management(V1, "VERTEX", "TEXT", 5, "", "", "refcode", "NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")

# Update CODE field with CODE_TEST value
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(V1, ["VERTEX"]) as cur:
    for count, row in enumerate(cur, start=1):
        value = f"V{count}"
        row[0] = value
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for count, row....`?

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd, posted edited.

Comment: In Python 2 it doesn't work, since there is no f-string in its library.

Comment: @pmurbina87 Python 2 is deprecated and you should use Python 3: https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/#:~:text=The%20sunset%20date%20has%20now,when%20we%20released%20Python%202.7. The work around is to use the old methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962966

Comment: @Aarón Hey, it worked with a list method! With the following line:

value = "V" + str(count)